# Singular indeterminate pronouns

Tags: pronoms

If I wanted to say a sentence like "who left their keys here" where the "their" is referring to a single person, do I use «leur/leurs» or «son/sa/ses»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In French, this pronoun agree with the object (the keys), not the owner (who) so is ***ses*** here:

> *Qui a laissé ses **clés** ici ?*

The fact of whether it is a single person or not, and their gender(s) is not explicit in the question, and doesn't need to be stated.